# Focus Edit Text Programmatically (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a `createEditText` function that creates an `EditText` and adds it to the view. My issue is that once it is added to the view, the user has to tap the `EditText` in order for the keyboard to be called and editing to work. What I am trying to do is to have it so that once the `EditText` is created, the user is automatically taken to the edit mode.

In IOS programming, there is a function called `becomeFirstResponder()` which achieves this. What would the android equivalent be?

Things I have tried:

```
myEditText.requestFocus()
myEditText.isActivated
myEditText.isFocused
myEditText.isSelected
myEditText.isEnabled
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not enough to call only `EditText#requestFocus`. In addition to this you also have to call the `InputMethodManager#showSoftInput`. Following utility method should work:

```
fun openSoftKeyboard(context: Context, view: View) {
    view.requestFocus()
    // open the soft keyboard
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea (a bit pseudo-code just to clarify things):

```
myEditText.requestFocus()
(activity or dialog).window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
```

You must take care of not showing the soft keyboard if there is a hardware keyboard connected

Comment: This is kotlin ??

Comment: What is `window`? When I am trying to type this code I cannot find it.

Comment: It is Activity.getWindow(), can be called from dialogs too.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<requestFocus />` in your your EditText view in xml file of layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not creating this `EditText` in an activity but in an adapter. As a result, there is no xml file.