# programically click EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, click, focus

I would like to programmatically click an editText once a button has been pressed.
When a radio button "pitot_area" is selected, I want the editText associated with this selection to be programmatically clicked, so the user has one less "click" on the screen and it happens automatically.

So far I have tried

```
performClick()
callOnClick()
requestFocus()
```

the area i would like this code to be within is below:

```
root.pitot_area.setOnClickListener {
setAreaLabels(root)         
evNodeItem.kvParams = false
evNodeItem.PitotRectArea = false
evNodeItem.PitotRoundArea = false
evNodeItem.areaParams = true

root.area_edit_text.requestFocus()
```

another method I have tried is

```
root.area_edit_text.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                root.area_edit_text.setFocusable(true);
                root.area_edit_text.requestFocus();
```

for the above lines of code, I have in the .xml file for the  editText

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusedByDefault="false"
```

An error does not show and the code builds, it seems this code is not read in kotlin? Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

**edit**
ive looked at-> Focus Edit Text Programmatically (Kotlin) question sugggested below and was unable to implement it for my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus Edit Text Programmatically (Kotlin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743467/focus-edit-text-programmatically-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set direct focus to the EditText you have to open keyboard after setting focus to the EditText.

write this lines into your button click:

For Activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    
    editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    editText.requestFocus()
        
    val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(llMainView.applicationWindowToken, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
        
}
```

For Fragment:

```
  button.setOnClickListener {
        
   editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
   editText.requestFocus()

   val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = activity!!.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
   inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(llMainView.applicationWindowToken, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I've just tried this and was given the error Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected with INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE underlined in read

Comment: I have added code for both Activity & Fragment

Comment: i cant seem to get this method to work any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried with the code I have added? its working fine in my code

Comment: fro the fragment code i am presented with the error unresolved reference llMainView, what am i suppose to substitute in for this?

Comment: llMainView is the id of  the root view of your XML layout  file